# How to make your own pagination Django

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

I have some json data from 3rd party API which has parameters like `3rd_party.com/API?NumberOfItemsOnPage=5&PageNumber1` NumberOfItemsOnPage - how many items will be on one page and PageNumber - current page. This json has items, info about current page, how many items on page and how many pages in general

And I want to know how can I paginate through that json using paginate_by in class `ListView`

```
class myView(ListView)

    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self, ...):
        queryset = []
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')

        # This might be wrong but I doesn't realy care because I need to know how to paginate using default django pagination
        request = f'3rd_party.com/API?NumberOfItemsOnPage=5&PageNumber{page_number}' 

        queryset = request.json()
        return queryset
```

I guess I need to override django Paginator class but I dont know how to do that because django paginator paginate will through only first page and won't get another's

Answer (score -1):

Here you will find the official documentation: [how to override pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

For my part, I follow the Style Guide of [HackSoftware](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide#filters--pagination):

For this you need to create your function `get_paginated_response`:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


def get_paginated_response(*, pagination_class, serializer_class, queryset, request, view):
    paginator = pagination_class()

    page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view=view)

    if page is not None:
        serializer = serializer_class(page, many=True)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = serializer_class(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

and call it like that:

```
class UserListApi(ApiErrorsMixin, APIView):
    class Pagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
        default_limit = 1

    class OutputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        id = serializers.CharField()
        email = serializers.CharField()
        is_admin = serializers.BooleanField()

    def get(self, request):
        users = user_list()

        return get_paginated_response(
            pagination_class=self.Pagination,
            serializer_class=self.OutputSerializer,
            queryset=users,
            request=request,
            view=self
        )
```

Comment: Im not using drf. I need override pagination in queryest in ListView django with my request json from another API and show that json data in my view

Comment: I understood that, and I gave you two alternatives. But apparently you wait for us to give you the code without even trying

Comment: I was not waiting for give me literally code i was just asking for help in ListView Django not Listview drf